# How implies "$\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_nx_n$ exists for every x $\in c_0$" that z $\in l^1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

If z is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_nx_n$ exists for every x $\in c_0$, how follows that z must be in $l^1$?

Comment: The simplest way - if you have the necessary instruments - is using the Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that you can choose the signs of the $x_n$ arbitrarily, so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |z_k x_k| < \infty$ holds for all $(x_k)_k \in c_0$.

This shows that the (linear!) map

$$
\Gamma : c_0 \rightarrow \ell^1, (x_k)_k \mapsto (z_k x_k)_k
$$

is well-defined.

Use the Closed-Graph-Theorem to conclude that it is continuous.

This shows that $(x_k)_k \mapsto \sum_k z_k x_k$ is indeed a bounded linear functional on $c_0$.

This should allow you to conclude the proof.